# How to mock $parent for vue-components

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils

How am i able to mock $parent for my specs? When using shallowMount with my component i always get clientWidth/clientHeight of undefined. I already tried mocking $parent as an object with an $el as a key and two more nested keys for clientWidth and clientHeight, but that's not working as expected. I cannot figure out the right usage of parentComponent.

I've got a single file component as seen below:

```
<template>
  <img :src="doSomething">
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Foobar",
  data() {
    return {
      size: null
    };
  },
  computed: {
    doSomething() {
      # here is some string concatenation etc.
      # but not necessary for example
      return this.size;
    }
  },
  created() {
    let parent = this.$parent.$el;
    this.size = `size=${parent.clientWidth}x${parent.clientHeight}`;
  }
};
</script>
```

creating the vue app looks like this:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Foobar from "./Foobar";

const vueEl = "[data-vue-app='foobar']";
if (document.querySelector(vueEl)) {
  new Vue({
    el: vueEl,
    components: {
      "foo-bar": Foobar
    }
  });
}
```

and the combination of using slim with my component looks like this:

```
div data-vue-app="foobar"
  foo-bar
```

This is my test setup:

```
import { shallowMount } from "@vue/test-utils";
import Foobar from "@/store/Foobar";

describe("Foobar.vue", () => {
  let component;

  beforeEach(() => {
    component = shallowMount(Foobar, {});
  });
```

Comment: I suspect it will involve manually defining those properties, but yeah, I can't seem to get the $parent to be anything other than undefined either - https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/1729

Comment: I have this working now, what version of vue-test-utils are you using, and can you update your code example to show how you used "parentComponent"

Comment: @chrismarx i've pinned vue-test-utils on "^1.0.0-beta.25"; i will update my code asap but i don't know exactly when i'll find time this week; either way, i tried using parentComponent with 2 ways: first way was a plain html string as given parameter and second way was creating a div with plain JS with document.createElement and passing it to the parentComponent option

Answer (score 5):

The parentComponent mounting option expects a component object:

```
import Parent from "../Parent.vue";
...
beforeEach(() => {
  component = shallowMount(Foobar, {
   parentComponent: Parent
  });
});
```

Also, try pinning the version of vue-test-utils to "^1.0.0-beta.28". This should allow your tests to complete, but the clientWidth/Height will still be 0x0

ref: https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/options.html#parentcomponent

Comment: thank you for your comment; however my parentComponent is actually not a vue-component. Instead it's pure html and i just mount my component on the html element. Using a parent vue component in my specs feels just wrong because it does not reflect the actual usage

Comment: You can make a component in the test if you want, even something as simple as this will work:
 let parentComponentStub = {
      name:"parentStub",
      template:'<div></div>'
    };